# Passing function name as callback doesn't work as expected in my class

Tags: php, function, class, callback

This seems straightforward, but the below code is giving the following error. Any suggestions?

> usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'cmp' not
>   found or invalid function name

My code:

```
function cmp($item1, $item2) {
    return strcmp(strtolower($item1->last_name), strtolower($item2->last_name));
}

public function get_people() {
    usort($this->my_array, 'cmp');
}
```

Comment: tried with "cmp" ? double quote?

Comment: @Goikiu: `'foo'` and `"foo"` are IDENTICAL as far as php is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `$this->my_array` and the function has the keyword public, I'm going to assume these two methods are in a class definition, so you also have to define, that you want to call a class method and not a normal function.

This means you have to change:

```
usort($this->my_array, 'cmp');
```

to:

```
usort($this->my_array, [$this, 'cmp']);
                      //^^^^^ So it will call the class method and not a normal global function
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have this within a class so there's two ways you can do this.

> first way, by telling it the method exists on the current class

```
public function get_people() {
    usort($this->my_array, array($this, 'cmp'));
}
```

> second way, using closures

```
public function get_people() {
    usort($this->my_array, function($item1, $item2) {
        return strcmp(strtolower($item1->last_name), strtolower($item2->last_name));
    });
}
```

I personally prefer the closure way as this function is only used by this sort function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're inside a class. There are many ways how to use class or object functions for callback, see [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.callable.php). Example:

```
  public function get_people() {
      usort($this->my_array, array($this, 'cmp'));
  }
```